# No quality profiles have been found, you probably don't have any language plugin installed

Tags: jenkins, sonarqube

CentOS 7

Java 8

SonarQube 5.6.3

Jenkins 2.289

Jenkinks plugin SonarScanner: 2.11

Success run sonarqube and open page

http://localhost:9000/

Nice.

But when I run Jenkin's job I get error:

```
ERROR: Error during SonarScanner execution
ERROR: No quality profiles have been found, you probably don't have any language plugin installed.
ERROR: 
ERROR: Re-run SonarScanner using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
WARN: Unable to locate 'report-task.txt' in the workspace. Did the SonarScanner succeeded?
ERROR: SonarQube scanner exited with non-zero code: 2
```

Comment: Sonarqube 5.6.3 is way out of support. I believe your up-to-date sonar-scanner tries to use API that may have changed since then.

Answer (score 2):

I have the same problem.
I solved it by installing jacoco and (java if needed) in Sonarqube : Administration -> Marketplace -> install jacoco, java code (if needed)
[image]